# How do I upvote you guys?

Tags: discussion

I really appreciate everyone who reached out to me and are helping me make a lens choice. I want to upvote you all, but it's not recording my clicks.

The fact that you spent your precious time (time is everything) helping a new forum member says everything I need to know about the character of the forum members:).

I hope someday I can help you all in some way the way you are helping me right now.

God Bless you all:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *is* recording your clicks, but they are registered as [anonymous feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99370/295232) rather than directly modifying the score. You'll only need a little bit more reputation, [15 to be exact](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), in order to upvote posts. Ask good questions, provide good answers, and/or [suggest a good edit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/editing) and you'll be there in no time.

Comment: And now that user @CamateurFlowtography is at 35, they can go back and upvote all the answers they want to!

Comment: Already done:) All well deserved upvotes. People here are just great!